# Why should one expect a ~30% drop in speed when using OpenVPN UDP with NordVPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, udp, internet-speed, nordvpn

https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/1047408902/Speed-and-bandwidth.htm  ([mirror](https://archive.ph/pyHyn)) mentions:

> If you are connected to the closest available server through OpenVPN UDP, you can expect around a 30% drop in speed.

Why should one expect a 30% drop in speed when using OpenVPN UDP  with NordVPN? Protocol overhead? Some other reasons? Is the reason specific to NordVPN?

---

I use the NordVPN program:

[image]

Comment: ***This is only a guess*** but UDP is not intended to be used for this sort of transmission.  It is connection-less.. that means to make it work, there needs to be some sort of mechanism to deal with packet loss and packet ordering.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: The point of the sentence isn't actually UDP. It is OpenVPN UDP. And the comparison is not about OpenVPN UDP vs OpenVPN TCP but between OpenVPN and no VPN at all.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: But, it's a VPN so it's carrying IP packets inside. It's supposed to be providing exactly the same kind of reliability that the (inner) IP layer already expects. So the question makes sense; "why would IP-in-UDP-in-IP be worse than IP alone".

Comment: Could closevoters "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic" explain their rationale instead of flagging my comments for removal?

Comment: So many questions at me.. I will try to answer them all.  Well.. a simple answer to OpenVPN vs No VPN.. every packet has to be wrapped using encryption thus wasting quite a few cycles.. AND those packets need to be routed around through the mechanism that actually does the VPN.  UDP even makes more work still.. @user1686.. the exact same reliability?  Is it, or is it not UDP?  Wrapping a packet in crypto hardly makes it TCP.  Perhaps I still don't understand.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: I wasn't talking about crypto nor about TCP in any way shape or form. I was saying that UDP provides the same reliability guarantees or lack thereof as IP itself -- not more, not less. If an IP packet has X% chance to get lost when sent directly, it should have the same X% chance to get lost when encapsulated in UDP/IP.

Comment: I am one of the close voters... The rational is that you are asking a question specific to a **service provider**, "**is the reason specific to nordVPN?...**" Maybe, but discussing service provider networks is definitely off-topic. Don't get too bent out of shape about it, we close questions like this all the time, and it's nothing personal. Although I have no idea who flagged your comments. If I think something is off-topic, I vote to close and see if the community agrees with my action. This is the system working as it should...

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Thanks for the comment. The question pertains to networking: understanding the impact of networking protocols on the connection speed. Besides, nordVPN is also a program.

Comment: If your question is just about the program, you should make that clear with an edit, I have read your question a couple times now. "**when using OpenVPN UDP with NordVPN?**" ~ this definitely sounds like you are using a openVPN client with nordVPN service, or did I misinterpret the question?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I use the NordVPN program with OpenVPN UDP: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxkOo.png

Comment: Yes, @user1686 , I never thought of it that way before.. however; I have known many experienced layer 3 programmers who have tried (and failed) to implement "their own" TCP over UDP that was as performant or reliable.  I do mean it though... I never thought about it that way until you just said it so THANKS! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why should one expect a 30% drop in speed when using OpenVPN UDP with NordVPN?

I think this questions needs a clarification first. The quote which this question is based on is not about OpenVPN UDP  vs. OpenVPN TCP but about OpenVPN UDP vs. using no VPN at all.

> Protocol overhead?

Yes

> Some other reasons?

Packets do not take a direct path to the target but will first travel (encrypted) to the VPN exit node and from their to the final target.

> Is the reason specific to NordVPN?

No, it is specific to the fact that a VPN is used and then to the specific VPN protocol. The overhead of OpenVPN is larger than the overhead of for example Wireguard. NordVPN even recommends Wireguard (NordLynx is based on Wireguard) for more speed.